# EditText.getText().toString() is Empty at onCreate() after setting data with ViewModel

Tags: java, android, mvvm, data-binding, android-databinding

I want to focus to the end of the `editText` when i get back to the activity from another activity. 
I Pass `viewName` with `Intent` to filter which View should be focused. 
I am using `ViewModel` - `Data Binding` Model class to set data to the `views`

**Problem**
I can get the values from intent and view also focused but I can not get the size of text to set the cursor to the end of the text in the `editText`. Though Values are set to each views , i can see and do other stuff with the values. Only problem is `getText().toString()` at the beginning to set focus at last.

`bindingName.viewName.getText().toString()` is always empty thus cursor stays at the beginning.

This problem occurs if i call the `requestFocus` in the onCreate() or onResume() state. but Works fine if I put this to some method which executes a bit later.

> Java Step1.class

```
public class Step1 extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, View.OnClickListener {
    Step1Binding step1Binding;
   ....
    SubmittedModel submittedModel;
    boolean isTerritorySet = false;
    boolean isCeNameSet = false;
    boolean isDistributorSet = false;
    boolean isPSRSet = false;
    boolean isInEditMode = false;
    String viewName;

    private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> areaList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        step1Binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.layout_step1);
       .....
        submittedModel = new SubmittedModel();
        submittedModel.setUser_id(UserInfo.getInstance().getUserInfo(this).getUserId());
        .....

        if (getIntent().hasExtra("value")) {
            submittedModel = (SubmittedModel) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("value");
            step1Binding.setSubmitData(submittedModel);
        }
        if (getIntent().hasExtra("edit")) {
            isInEditMode = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("edit", false);
            if (isInEditMode) {
                step1Binding.backBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
        if (getIntent().hasExtra("viewName")){
            viewName =getIntent().getStringExtra("viewName");
            requestFocusOnSelectedView();  //Method to select views
        }

        .....
    }

    .......

    void requestFocusOnSelectedView() {
        //request focus
        if (isInEditMode & viewName != null) {
            switch (viewName) {
                case ViewName.territory:
                    step1Binding.territoryList.requestFocus();
                    break;
                case ViewName.ceName:
                    step1Binding.ceNameList.requestFocus();
                    break;
                case ViewName.distributor:
                    step1Binding.distributorList.requestFocus();
                    break;
                case ViewName.psr:
                    step1Binding.psrNameList.requestFocus();
                    break;
                case ViewName.subRoute:
                    step1Binding.subRoute.requestFocus();
                    step1Binding.subRoute.setSelection(step1Binding.subRoute.getText().length());
                    break;
                case ViewName.outlet:
                    step1Binding.outletName.requestFocus();
                    step1Binding.outletName.setSelection(step1Binding.outletName.getText().length());
                    break;
                case ViewName.retailerName:
                    step1Binding.retailerName.requestFocus();
                    step1Binding.retailerName.setSelection(step1Binding.retailerName.getText().length());
                    break;
                case ViewName.retailerMobile:
                    step1Binding.retailerMobile.requestFocus();
                    step1Binding.retailerMobile.setSelection(step1Binding.retailerMobile.getText().length());
                    break;
                case ViewName.address:
                    step1Binding.address.requestFocus();
                    step1Binding.address.setSelection(step1Binding.address.getText().length());
                    break;


            }
        }
    }

}
```

> XML + DATA Model : Code works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After setting all your data, but before requesting focus, call

```
binding.executePendingBindings();
```

This will force the View values to be set.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
view.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        theView2Focus.requestFocus();
    }
});
```

Your problem is that you have to wait until the UI is created. That is exactly what you detected.

Comment: i didn't get which should be the `view` ?

Comment: Try `step1Binding.getRoot()`